# Why is my input field invisible when type = 'text'?

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

Why are my input fields invisible until I click on them? I set the type to text. I'm using React and Tailwind.

[image: This is a picture of the input fields:]

This is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";

export default function LoginModal({ open, onClose, openSignUp }) {
  if (!open) return null;

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 bg-white p-5 z-10 drop-shadow-2xl animate-fadein rounded-lg">
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClose} className="ml-auto">
          {" "}
          <CloseIcon />{" "}
        </button>
        <form action="POST" className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
          <div className="space-x-2">
            <label for="email" className="">
              Email
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
          </div>
          <div className="space-x-2">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" />
          </div>
          <input className="" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <a className="button m-0" onClick={openSignUp}>
          {" "}
          Sign Up{" "}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a border color or a background color to the input and it should be visible

Answer (score 0):

Your input box is there but with 0 border, Just add CSS or style to add border and other style and it will be visible.